# yargs.parse error from webpack.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to install and use webpack for the first time. After installation I made a small webpack.config.js file:

```
  module.exports = {
      context: __dirname + "/assets/js",

      entry: "./react/index.js",

      output: {
      filename: "app.js",
      path: __dirname + "/public/assets/js"
  }
};
```

Then to run webpack I do:

`node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`

This gives me the following error:

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:152
yargs.parse(process.argv.slice(2), (err, argv, output) => {
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

How to fix it?

Comment: try installing webpack globally, so you can just run by calling `webpack`. That might fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Redhat Enterprise Linux. I discovered that if you use the node and npm versions downloaded from https://nodejs.org, this fixes the problem. Don't use yum or apt-get to install nodejs.